# What Is The Point In The Extra Inventory Tab In Hexxit?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-hexxit

I have been playing hexxit for a while now and I have tried to equip stuff to this extra inventory tab, but it doesn't seem to change anything (at least not cosmetically). I equipped a shield, and it doesn't seem to do anything at all. So what is the actual point of this tab (as seen below)?[image]

Answer (score 2):

If the bag slot is equipped with a knapsack, then you get extra inventory space in a new tab (equivalent to a single wooden chest).

Answer (score 2):

The heart container looking thing gives a permanent added health bonus.

You can get a full extra bar with 10 of them.

Comment: Do you know what the item is actually called?

Comment: @ReallyGoodPie heart canister

Answer (score 0):

Amulets go in the very top equip spots to the left (pyro, geo, aero amulets)

Comment: And how exactly do I activate these while they are in this slot?